# How to show "Read-only" (un-editable) content in a grid? Has to be a non-color reliant way so can't use gray color

Tags: grid, inline-edit, edit

How to show "Read-only" (un-editable) content in a grid? Has to be a non-color reliant way so can't use gray color. FYI, some content in this grid will be editable and the way it works is, it's just plain black text. User just clicks on it and it becomes editable. Also, I read a lot here on how to show "Read-only" form fields.

Comment: Non-color means it has to be black or white? Can the cells be black and the text white to distinguish them?

Comment: Is this a desktop application, web application, or mobile app? You say you can't use color—why not? Are you trying to optimize for a print format, or are you constrained by technologies? Just wondering what you have available to work with.

Comment: @Steve Knockout is an interesting idea. I suppose I can do that. It would be a bit harsh visually though.

Comment: @maxathousand Has to be a non-color reliant way, to be ADA compliant, and because apparently, our users complain when we use gray text (that's what I'm told). Even if it passes AA standard for "Normal" text - which it does.

Comment: This could be a XY problem. Is there any affordance that you can edit the editable text?